# Mock external http requests in grails

Tags: unit-testing, rest, grails, groovy, mocking

I am using RestBuilder ([LINK](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/)) for making REST calls to outer services. 
Now I want to mock that http requests for unit testing (or integration testing, whatever) service that handles all logic about communication with that outer services.

Does anyone know how to mock http requests or this RestBuilder maybe?

Thanks for any help!
Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of test is called «functional test». There are many plugins that can help you with this task:

http://www.grails.org/plugin/functional-test

http://www.grails.org/plugins/tag/functional

Comment: Thanks. Problem is that all our functional tests are written in Spock framework if I see well on their documentation says that spock doesn't support functional testing :/

Comment: it kind of does, you might need to use it with geb. See the Grails website project for exemple: https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website/

Comment: When you're testing a code which is making requests to external services and you mock those external requests, the result is proper unit test. It's not a functional test in any way.

Comment: Well, in the context of grails at that time, it was. In a broader context, I agree with you...